Invertibility of a measurable mapping from lower and upperbounds on the induced pushforward measure
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open and consider the standard Borel space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}(\Omega), \mu)$, where $\mu$ denotes the Lebeasgue measure. Let $f: \Omega \to \Omega$ be a measurable mapping and denote by $f_\# \mu$ the pushforward measure defined by
$$
f_\#\mu(B) := \mu(f^{-1}(B)) \quad \text{ for any B in } \mathcal{B}.
$$
Assume that $f_\# \mu \ll \mu$, i.e., $f_\# \mu$ is absolutely continuous and assume that there exist $c,C >0$ such that
$$
c \leq d f_\#\mu /d \mu \leq C \quad \text{a.e.},
$$
where $d f_\#\mu /d \mu$ denotes the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $f_\# \mu$. Note that the measures $\mu$ and $f_\# \mu$ are equivalent in this case.
Question: Does it follow that $f$ is an invertible function, i.e., is there a measurable mapping $\phi: \Omega \to \Omega$ such that $(f \circ \phi)(x) = (\phi \circ f)(x) = x \ a.e.$?
If yes, are the lower and upperbounds on the the Radon-Nikodym derivative necessary for the invertibility of $f$?

Thoughts
The result is trivial in this case where $f$ is a differentiable mapping. In this case, the Radon Nikodym derivative agrees with the derivative in the sense of Lebesgue and the result follows by the inverse function theorem. Moreover, $f$ is a bi-Lipschitz function.
A partial answer
One result from descriptive set theory seems to be useful when $f$ is less regular. However, the result seems to be restricted to a finite measure $\mu$.

Theorem [5.2. in Varadrajan, geometry of a quantum theory, Vol. II]
Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard Borel spaces and $f$ be a Borel map on $X$. Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $X$. Then, the range of $f(X)$ is $f_\# \mu$-measurable and its complement has $f_\# \mu$-measure zero. Moreover, there exist Borel sets $K\subseteq X$ and $Z \subseteq f(\Omega)$ s.t. $f_\#\mu (Y \setminus Z)=0$ and $f$ is one-to-one on $K$ and maps $K$ onto $Z$.

In our case, $Y=X=\Omega$. The cited theorem implies that there exist two sets $K \subseteq \Omega$ and $Z \subseteq f(\Omega)$ such that f is one-to-one on $K$ and maps $K$ onto $Z$. Moreover, $f_\#\mu (\Omega \setminus Z)=0$. Since $\mu \ll f_\#\mu$ it follows that $\mu(\Omega \setminus Z) =0$. We can now define $\phi:=(f|_K)^{-1}$. Note that $\phi$ has domain $Z$ and range $K$. Since $f$ is one-to-one on $K$, it follows by Kuratowski's theorem that $\phi$ is measurable. Hence $(f \circ \phi)(x) = x \ a.e.$ and theorefore $f$ is onto.
To prove that $f$ is one-to-one we need to show that $(\phi \circ f)(x)=x \ a.e.$. Clearly, this holds for any $x$ in $K$. It remains then to prove that $\mu (X \setminus K)=0$. I'm not sure how to show this.
